# MVC - data classes - only subset of properties are needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

for example, question class would have questionid, title, content, time posted, poster, tags, etc. This is how the fetching data looks like:

```
 public bool LoadFromDataRow(DataRow row)
        {
            questionId = (long)row["questionId"]; 
            content = (string)row["content"];
            poster = (string)row["poster"];
            datePosted = (DateTime)row["datePosted "];
            title = (string)row["title"];
            return true;
        }
```

however, there might be a time when I am only selecting a subset of these properties like questionid and title. Do I need to write another class to handle this? Or do I need to check for every single column before I fetch the value with something like this:

```
if(row.hascolumns(...)) // seems like overkill?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it is fine to have your repository method return a model with all properties being mapped but then use a view model when time comes to display/edit this model on a view. Then perform a mapping between you model and you view model (which would be a subset of the model) and in your view work with the view model. There's an exception to this: BLOBs. If you are storing binary data such as images in the database I would recommend you having two separate methods: one that fetches the images and one that doesn't.

Comment: but if there are 15 fields, and I need only 2, and there are a lot of such records on the page, isn't it like I am sending unnecessary data from my SQL Server...?  Or you think the time to fetch 13 extra fields per record is negligible?

Comment: Yes indeed, you will be performing an SQL query which will fetch 15 fields but display only 5. I wouldn't worry much about this and IMO it will be a negligible performance hit compared to the execution of the query itself. Of course you should measure the performance to make sure that this doesn't become a bottleneck to the application.